# Passing common prop to all components in MDX file, without adding the prop to each component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, mdxjs, gatsby-plugin-mdx

I've got mdx files with components that need to be locale aware.

Lots of components.
And they all need to be locale-aware.

In the .mdx files, I can change them from this:

```
<FirstDayOfMonth/>
```

to that:

```
<FirstDayOfMonth lang="fr"/>
```

But then I'd need to do it for every component in every .mdx file.

Is there a way to make a prop available to all components used in mdx?

---

I thought of passing it to the MDXRenderer, something like this:

```
<MDXProvider>
  <MDXRenderer lang={currentLang}>{body}</MDXRenderer>
</MDXProvider>
```

Or accessing the frontmatter from the components.

But both approaches are not documented and didn't give any results.

Better ideas?

---

per request, list of relevant dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "gatsby": "^3.6.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-copy-files-enhanced": "^1.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^2.11.0",
    "preact": "^10.5.13",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.1.19",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue and am looking for an answer too!

Comment: how/where are you using MDX? is it in gatsby?

Comment: In my case, yes, Gatsby (But Ferran Buireu edited those tags out )

Comment: could you please share the version of the packages you're using? react, gatsby, plugins, etc.

Comment: Sure, edited those in.

Answer (score 4):

You could add those props when [passing the shortcodes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/importing-and-using-components/#make-components-available-globally-as-shortcodes) to the `MDXProvider` by iterating through the map and returning new components with the default props injected.

```
import FirstDayOfMonth from 'path/to/FirstDayOfMonth';

const addProps = (components, defaultProps) => {
  const withProps = {};

  for (const [key, Component] of Object.entries(components)) {
    withProps[key] = (props) => <Component {...defaultProps} {...props} />
  }

  return withProps;
}

const shortcodes = { FirstDayOfMonth, SomeOtherComponent };

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const someDefaultProps = {
    lang: "fr",
    something: "else",
  };

  const shortcodesWithProps = useMemo(
    () => addProps(shortcodes, someDefaultProps),
    someDefaultProps
  );

  return (
        ...
        <>
          <MDXProvider components={shortcodesWithProps}>
            {children}
          </MDXProvider>
        </>
       ...
  );
};
```